# How do i get validation to work in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I'm learning MVC but i cant get the validation to work.

I read that i can do annotations in my models like this:

```
 public class InvoiceNoModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Invoice Number")]
    public string InvoiceNo { get; set; }
}
```

I did that and in my view i have this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("GetInvoice","WebPay", FormMethod.Post))
{
<p class="flat">@Html.ValidationSummary(true) </p>
<p class="flat">
        @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.InvoiceNo)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.InvoiceNo)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.InvoiceNo)
</p>
<input class="button-1 search-box-button" value="GO" type="submit" />

}
```

When i run my app and click GO without entering any value in invoiceno input field i expected it to fail with a message displayed to the user...but this isnt the case and it flies right into the action...
I know i'm missing something but cant figure it out...and d book didnt say :)
Thanks

Comment: Does the generated HTML for the textbox have the `data-val="true"` and the `data-val-required="The Invoice Number field is required."` attributes to it?

Answer (score 0):

you must be missing the link to js files that are responsible for client side validation..

Comment: How do u mean?do i need to include any js files?how do i do that? thanks

Comment: just drag and drop the jquery.validate.js and jquery.validate.unbtusive.js into your _Layout.cshtml or the view where you need client side validation.. let me know if it works.. cheers..

Comment: Note that if you are using Bundling, there will probably be a `"~/bundles/jqueryval"` bundle defined. Just add that to your layout: `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")`

Comment: i have these two lines `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
  @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)` in my layout but it still doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

I got it working after pouring through a lot of answers on SO and trying them out.
It turned outs that the unobtrusive validation scripts were not loaded by default. I fixed it by adding at the end of _Layout.cshtml

`@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")`

The end result:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Answer (score 0):

Set ValidationSummary(false) or just blank ValidationSummary() , it will work then

```
     @using (Html.BeginForm("GetInvoice","WebPay", FormMethod.Post))
       {
         <p class="flat">@Html.ValidationSummary(true) </p>
         <p class="flat">
         @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.InvoiceNo)
         @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.InvoiceNo)
         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.InvoiceNo)
         </p>
         <input class="button-1 search-box-button" value="GO" type="submit" />

       }
```